# Parallel transport geometric phase derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differential-geometry, quantum-information, quantum-optics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

In *Modern Foundations of Quantum Optics* by Vlatko Vedral, he derives an expression for the change in phase under parallel transport after completing a small loop as

$$\begin{align} \delta \theta &= \arg \{\langle \psi(s_i)\vert\psi(s_i+\delta s)\rangle\langle \psi(s_i+\delta s)\vert\psi(s_i+\delta s+\delta s')\rangle\langle \psi(s_i+\delta s+\delta s')\vert\psi(s_i)\rangle\} \\[1em]&=\arg\left\{1+i\left(\frac{\delta}{\delta s}\langle \psi(s_i)\rvert   \frac{\delta}{\delta s'} \lvert\psi(s_i)\rangle-\frac{\delta}{\delta s'}\langle \psi(s_i)\rvert   \frac{\delta}{\delta s}\lvert\psi(s_i)\rangle\right)\right\} \\[1em]&= \frac{\delta}{\delta s}\langle \psi(s_i)\rvert   \frac{\delta}{\delta s'} \lvert\psi(s_i)\rangle-\frac{\delta}{\delta s'}\langle \psi(s_i)\rvert   \frac{\delta}{\delta s}\lvert\psi(s_i)\rangle.\end{align}$$

How is the second line obtained? Firstly, I am not even sure what the notation means, as it seems like functional derivatives have come out of nowhere. But even without this, how does e.g. a factor of $i$ arise, and the relative minus sign? I have tried expanding it but can't get it into anything like the given form.